# AngularJS Error: Getting ng:areq Bad Argument in declaring my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really new to Angular and I haven't been able to find a solution for the "Bad Argument" error I'm getting with the controller I'm trying to use. 
I'm not sure if it's something else entirely or how I've defined the controller itself.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

## The JS

```
app.controller('questionCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

            console.log('question posting is ready');
            var questionText = $('input[id="qASectionHead"]').val();
            var businessIdNo = localStorage.getItem('vm.id');
            console.log(businessIdNo);

            $scope.askButton = function() {

                console.log('ask has been clicked')

                console.log('The user has typed: ' + questionText);

                $http({
                    url: 'url',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        question_text: questionText,
                        business_id: businessIdNo,
                    },
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'token'
                    },
                }).success(function(data) {

                    console.log(data);
                    });
                  };
                }]);
```

## The HTML

```
              <div id="qASectionContain" ng-controller="questionCtrl">
            <input id="qASectionHead" placeholder="ask this business a question">
              <button ng-click="askButton()">
               ask
              </button>
```

Comment: Everything seems fine you provide a fiddle or plunkr

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with what you've provided which means the error must be somewhere else. Perhaps you could show more (all?) of your controller code?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I went ahead and added the rest of my controller code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The mystery has been solved!
It helps if the js file is linked correctly in your index..... [oops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuzqB.png)

Thanks to those who commented!